# Running multiprocess python module from C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x, .net, multiprocessing, python.net

## **Multiprocess Custom Python module ("area.py")**

I have a custom python module that runs CPU bound task on multicores using multiprocess python library. This function also has some numpy and scipy libraries for calculating trapezoidal or simpson's rule.

## Main C# Application**

I have to call the python module from the C# (.NET Framework 4.8) and I was looking for options and thought of the 3 possible options in the order of preference.

**pythonnet**

- Supports Python and recommended by .NET foundation and hence this was my first choice.
- However it looks like they don't support multiprocess as they use GIL lock from below example- [GitHub](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet)
- I have my pseudo code written below. When I run the multiprocess "area.py" file, my system crashes and I cannot run without Py.GIL() statement enabled as that throws memory protection error.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        var script= Py.Import("area");
        script.InvokeMethod("area");

    }
}
```

- Is there a way to run multiprocess py module using pythonnet?

**IronPython**

- Next option is to use IronPython which also supports multithreading but I see most of the articles suggesting to avoid this as this may soon become obsolete and also the updates are slow. (still stuck at python 3.4).

**Executable**

- My last approach would be run the area.py files as an executable rather than .py module or convert the existing python module to C#.

**Next Step**

- I have so far tried Pythonnet option.
- It runs fine with single process python module but fails with multi process python module file.
- What is the best option in this situation?

Comment: Have you considered porting the code to C#? Python will not be great at compute bound tasks no matter what you do. This is usually handled by offloading compute bounds stuff to C libraries. But you can call C libraries from c# as well, and there are likely .Net libraries that provide the same functionality.

Comment: Yeah I may consider that as final approach if none of the options works. I have to port my existing code to C# in this case. I know C# had deedle equivalent to pandas, NumSharp which is equivalent to numpy.  I would stay Python multiprocess is handy in multicore programming.